# Workflow information combine to one view/list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I current have a list setup in sharepoint, with workflow created.

I have created the rule using custom workflow created in designer.

1)First guy fills in content of list and starts the workflow. 2) 2nd guy is assigned certain information to provide, and he does that. 3) 3rd guy will need information from both guys and make decision (approved or rejected).

My issues is when 3rd guy is assigned to the task, he can only view stuff from 1st guy. Seeing the information from the 2nd guy is a lot harder and not that clear.

Does anyone know if I am able to have view where the 2nd guys information is added to the view for 3rd guy (or similar). its really annoying me.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you trigger email skeet

Answer (score 0):

If the 2nd guys information is on the list item then you should be able to just add those fields to the list view or create a new view for just those fields.

Comment: but when guy completes his view, Can i trigger email to let 2nd guy know something is waiting for him?

Comment: Yes.  You will just be looking for the fields to be populated and send an email based on that.  What version of workflow are you working with 2010 or 2013?  2013 you can just pause for a change or I have even polled the list if that is needed.

Comment: 2010.

Can you please send any articles. I could now find the option in the list to allow for sending of emails.

Comment: This document lists all of the actions you should see in 2010 workflows.  There is a "Send an Email" action.  It notes that outgoing email must be configured in Central Admin. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I made some progress with a custom workflow.

The issue i have now:
Person 1 fills in form, and Person 2 assigned and gets email.
Person 2 fills in form, Person 3 assigned.

person 3 can only see what person 1 filled in. To find what person 2 did he has to go into workflow and look for it. 

Would you know how to combine Person 1 and person 2 things to one view.

Comment: When you talk about filling in the form for Person 2, is that the task form?  Not the original list item form, correct?  I haven't worked with those specifically, but you'd have to query for that workflow task item and read the contents from that list.  I would suggest that you not have Person 2 use the task form but point that user back to edit the original list item.